# Get parameters from friendly URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, umbraco

I have some URLs which are then made friendly using Webforms/ Umbraco but not MVC i.e.

> **www.mysite.com/p=1&c=2&d=3**

to

> **www.mysite.com/1/2/3/ProductName**

The problem I come across after adding a friendly URL within the UrlRewriting.config is that when the friendly URL is used the parameters are coming in together i.e. 1/2/3 so when using

```
string pid = Server.HtmlDecode(Request.QueryString["p"]);
```

I get the value coming back as `1/2/3`. I use HTMLDecode as the value initially is encoded (i.e. slash is encoded).

I know i can put them into an array/list and get the relevant value but wondering if there is a better way or a preferred way i should be doing this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

The format `www.mysite.com/ProductName/1/2/3/` is used with routes (common with web Api).

But you need to use `RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes` in `Global.asax.cs` file.

small example

```cs
        void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            //Example: https://my.syte.com/updatedns/qft
            routes.MapPageRoute("updateDNS", "public/updateDNS/{hostname}",
                "~/pages/public/updateDNS.aspx"
                , false
                );
        }
```

How to add Global.asax

- Right clicking your website -> Add New Item -> Global Application Class -> Add

You need to add a class

- Right clicking App_Code -> Add New Item -> Class -> name it Global.cs -> Add

In `Global.asax`

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" Inherits="Global" %>
```

In `Global.asax.cs` (for your case)

```cs
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    }

    /// Many other events like begin request...e.t.c

    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //Example: https://my.syte.com/updatedns/qft
        routes.MapPageRoute("updateDNS", "public/updateDNS/{hostname}",
                "~/pages/public/updateDNS.aspx"
                , false
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think thats MVC? Sorry i'm not using MVC but i will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: You can use ´global.asax´ without MVC, just add it to your project.

Comment: In fact I don't use MVC projects. :)

Comment: Routing does not depend on MVC, in fact MVC depends on Routing. So you should be able to use it in your webforms project just fine.

Comment: This is an Umbraco question - in Umbraco, all routes are controlled by Umbraco and you can't register your own routes like the above.